# What is bad in my CLIPS code - or/and varying or else-if grammatic?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips

This is my CLIPS code that I am going to connect with Java code.
When I am trying to load in WinCLIPS it is written as FALSE.

I think that the problem could be with or/and or if-else syntax.

```
(deftemplate diagnoza
(slot wiek)
(slot klasa)
)

(deftemplate result
(slot value)
)

(defrule wiek-klasa-rule 
 (diagnoza (wiek ?w))
 (diagnoza (klasa ?g))
 =>
(if (and (< ?w 19)(> ?g 4))) 
    then
    (bind ?x "Wiek szkolny - ok.")
    (printout t ?x crlf)
    (assert (result (value ?x)))

(if (< ?w 4)) 
    then
    (bind ?x "Wiek poniżej 4 lat. Nie można zdiagnozować.")
    (printout t ?x crlf)
    (assert (result (value ?x)))

(if (> ?w 19)) 
    then
    (bind ?x "Wiek powyżej 19 lat. Nie można zdiagnozować.")
    (printout t ?x crlf)
    (assert (result (value ?x)))

else 
    (bind ?w "Nieprawidłowa wartość wieku. Nie można zdiagnozować.")
    (printout t ?x crlf) 
    (assert (result (value ?x)))
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are unbalanced. If you indent your code to reflect the depth of nesting, you can see where you've made errors:

```
(defrule wiek-klasa-rule 
   (diagnoza (wiek ?w))
   (diagnoza (klasa ?g))
 =>
   (if (and (< ?w 19)
            (> ?g 4)
       )
   ) 
   then
   (bind ?x "Wiek szkolny - ok.")
   (printout t ?x crlf)
   (assert (result (value ?x)
           )
   )
   (if (< ?w 4)
   ) 
   then
   (bind ?x "Wiek poniżej 4 lat. Nie można zdiagnozować.")
   (printout t ?x crlf)
   (assert (result (value ?x)
           )
   )
   (if (> ?w 19)
   ) 
   then
   (bind ?x "Wiek powyżej 19 lat. Nie można zdiagnozować.")
   (printout t ?x crlf)
   (assert (result (value ?x)))
   else 
   (bind ?w "Nieprawidłowa wartość wieku. Nie można zdiagnozować.")
   (printout t ?x crlf) 
   (assert (result (value ?x)))
)
```